# Fixing OpenSSL vulnerability in IIS

Tags: security, iis, openssl

I ran my website through a security testing tool which said the site fails because it is vulnerable to OpenSSL CCS vulnerability (CVE-2014-0224). This is not my area of expertise and I thought OpenSSL had to do with Linux and our websites are hosted on IIS. I cannot find any information online on how to resolve this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) would be a better place to ask. As Fisher commented, IIS use [SChannel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380123%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and not OpenSSL.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, IIS has it's own SSL/TLS implementation.

It might be that you're just getting a false positive. Try using another tool and double check the result.